# xml-comments of nuget package do not show up

Tags: c#, nuget, xml-comments

I have created my own nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chia-Client-API/

In the code of the package, I documented all functions with xaml comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// returns all subwallets of the currently logged in wallet
/// </summary>
/// <param name="includeData">Set to true to include all coin info for this wallet</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static GetWallets_Response GetWallets_Sync(bool includeData = true)
{
    Task<GetWallets_Response> data = Task.Run(() => GetWallets_Async(includeData));
    data.Wait();
    return data.Result;
}
```

in my other solution, I added the package through nuget package manager. The code works as expected but intellisense will not display the xaml comment information:
[image]

Is there something which is missing or which I have to enable in order to show the markup?

I have tried publishing a .snupkg according to official documentation but it did not change:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but is the nupkg a Debug or Release build?

Comment: it is a release build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seemed to work by adjusting the build settings of the project:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is a quick way to do this for all Projects in a Solution....

Comment: you can edit the solution file. the file is text based and this could be done programatically. Unfortunately, if they changed something, this would screw you up.